# How to code input validation on focusout in Meteor JS?

Tags: validation, meteor, input, meteor-blaze

How to validate input fields on focusout before going for the next input field in Meteor JS? Like in AngularJS.

Comment: if you're using autoforms, there is an option for you to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach an event handler to the field's `change` event, for example:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'change #myField'(event) {
    // do your validation here
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `focusout` on the events like this

```
Template.templateName.events({
  'focusout #inputId' (event, instance) {
    // insert code in here :D 
  }
});
```